# How to save initial state value in a variable vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, nuxt.js, vuex

I have an object with some data in the vuex store that I will need to use in a component,I have accessed the data with a getter in the component. I am trying to save the initial value of that object in a variable in a way that it doesn't change/update when the data in the store changes, this will allow me to do a comparison condition.

the code is below, the object accessed by 'getSelectedLocation' is what I need the original value of kept.

```
data() {
 return {
   toggle: this.getSelectedLocation?.local,
 }
},
computed: {
 ...mapGetters({ getUser: 'user/getUser', getSelectedLocation: 'support/getSelectedLocation' }),
},
methods: {
 async updateUsersLocation() {
   const usersCol = new UsersCollection(this.$fire.firestore)
   const id = this.getUser.id
   const location = this.getSelectedLocation
   return await usersCol.updateUsersLocation({ id, location })
 },
},
}
```

Comment: I think the answer that @Igor Moraru show you will do the work. Just to be clear you want to save in a function variable or a component variable (in your data)?

Answer (score 1):

You need two things. First to make a copy of that object, so it cannot change by reference the initial object, then to freeze it, so it cannot change itself.

```
const copy = Object.assign({}, this.getSelectedLocation())
Object.freeze(copy)
```

Comment: Just in case the `Object.assign` doesn't work you `JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(this.getSelectedLocation())`